# Can I do calculations on two tables and add the result in a specific column in one of those tables?

Tags: mysql, database

Ok say I have two tables Product and Sales
The product contains the id, name and price. The sales contains total-items, sold-items..
I want to get the price from product table and multiply it by sold-items from sales table and store the result in the column amount-sold in the sales table.

How can I do that ? using MySQL and on a MS SQL server  2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Sales 
set `amount-sold` = 
  `sold-items` * 
  (select ifnull(price, 0) 
   from Product 
   where Product.id=Sales.product_id);
```

Comment: Oh nice, yeah, thats better than mine :o)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data:

```
SELECT p.`price`,s.`sold-items` FROM `product` AS p INNER JOIN `sales` AS s ON s.`id`=p.`id` WHERE p.`id` = 123
```

Store the query result in a variable and then do the multiplication and then insert the data back in.

```
UPDATE `sales` SET `amount-sold` = {NEW VALUE} WHERE `id` = 123
```